# What is wrong with this Makefile? (header files not found)

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile

I am modifying an old makefile in order to build a C extension for postgreSQL. The Makefile currently looks like this:

```
PGLIB = /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/lib
PQINC = /usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server        
CC=gcc

override CFLAGS+= $(CFLAGS_SL) -DPG_AGGREGATE 

SHLIB = pg_myextlib

SRC =  foo.c \
       foobar.c

OBJS = foo.o \       
       foobar.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $(SHLIB)$(DLSUFFIX) $(OBJS) -I$(PQINC)
    cp *.so $(PGLIB)

clean:
    rm -f $(SHLIB) $(OBJS)
```

The error I get when I run make is:

> common.h:58:22: error: postgres.h: No such file or directory

Which suggests that the include path is not being added (the file exists in $PQINC).
Its a long time since I wrote the Makefile - and I haven't written many since. As an aside, I am pretty sure that 'shared' is not the gcc flag to build shared libs on Ubuntu (my current dev box) - I think the flag should be 'fPIC' - can someone confirm this?

I am runing gcc v4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.0.4 and compiling for use with PG 8.4

Comment: The -shared is needed at linker stage to produce a shared lib. The -fPIC is needed at compile stage to produce Position Independent Code that will be used in the shared lib. (the -fPIC can be added in the CFLAGS line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the `-I$(PQINC)` from target `all` to the end of line that starts with `override CFLAGS`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out *EXACTLY* what to do. Compiles successfully now. I'm just trying to resolve current linkage errors before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Placing `-Isomething` on the compiler line which turns *object* files, like those in `$(OBJS)`, into executable will have no effect whatsoever.

You need to do it when you compile the *source* files.

Since your makefile doesn't explicitly show the rule for processing source files, it may well be using a default one, which is incredibly unlikely to know about `PQINC`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the default rules to build foo.o from foo.c, which doesn't have your `-I`. Try adding the following rule to your Makefile:

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I$(PQINC)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `-I$(PQINC)` to `$(CFLAGS)`.